# Call Activity1's method from Activity 2

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity2 which needs to call method update() inside Activity1. How can I do this?

I don't want to start Activity2, just call it's method (this is because activity1 is the viewpager and activity2 is a fragment, so technically, activity1 is already visible as it is holding activity2.

Comment: See here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html you could implement your own interfaces to deliver data from Fragment to Activity and the other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Activity(context).methodname();
```

or

```
Activity.methodname();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call [getActivity ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) inside fragment, cast it to your class and use method.

Answer (score 0):

Activity can't hold another activity. If you mean that from first activity you will start intent with second activity which contains fragment, and you want to call `update()` method from activity2, you can't do that. You need call `update()` in `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

If "Activity2" is a fragment that has been started from Activity1 then this is what I would do:

((Activity1)getActivity()).someMethod();